# Spark 3.0 - Read data from an MQTT steam

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, mqtt, mosquitto

I would like to read data stream from a mosquitto based MQTT topic into my Spark 3.0 application. I tried with the Bahir library the following way:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
           .readStream()
           .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
           .option("topic", "mytopic")
           .load("tcp://localhost:1883");
```

Unfortunately this has failed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport
```

Apparently this only works with the 2.x Spark. Any idea how to make this working with Spark 3 (or with a different lib)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the available libraries [here, (see picture below)](https://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/) it does not look that that this library is already available for Spark 3.x. Also, I am not aware of any other public library.

[image]